# What precautions to take on removing users from Github Enterprise?

Tags: github

I know that I should take ownership of any personal repositories (and gists, etc) they have that might contain company data before removal.  However, what's the impact on repositories belonging to an organization that they were contributing to?

Does the user removal affect history or data integrity in any way that I need to be aware of?  In other words, is it safe to remove users or will it make bad things happen to all our important work?  :-)